# Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: The MySQL adapter mysqli is not available

Tags: php, joomla

I do not get what to do and I have tried everything but I still face this problem.

> Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: The MySQL adapter mysqli is not available

Comment: did you install mysqli support for php? is it activated?

Comment: Ask your host to enable mysqli support

Comment: Activated in `php.ini`?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel yes i hav installed mysql,it is accessible through command prompt.

Comment: @upendrasinghsengar - there's a difference between `mysql` the database, which you can access through the command prompt, and mysqli support in PHP. As Marcel suggests - check your php.ini and make sure that PHP has mysqli support enabled.

Comment: No, that's something different. Enable mysqli support by adding/uncommenting `extension=mysqli.so` in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup changes in php.ini can make it possible to connect with the mysqli..thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var $dbtype = 'mysqli';
```

to

```
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
```

thats all

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem too... I solved it by use the same username and password when the first time I installed my XAMPP. I didn't change any configuration on php.ini at all... :-)